# PayPal Integration(Needs advice)

Tags: paypal

I'm planning to integrate paypal to my website. I just need some few advice on which API should I use with the following scenario.

1. Once user was logged in to my site, he/she can link his/her paypal account to my website once and simply make paypal transactions without logging in again from paypal website.

Thanks in advance

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get that done, but with limited details I would recommend [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).

- SetExpressCheckout
- GetExpressCheckoutDetails
- DoExpressCheckoutPayment (If you're processing an initial payment as well as setting up the billing agreement)
- CreateBillingAgreement (if all you're doing is setting up a billing agreement without an initial charge.)

This [documentation about setting up billing agreements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/) provides more details on all of that.

If you are working with PHP this [PHP SDK for PayPal](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the API calls very simple for you.